# Using SortableRows and know when rows have been moved

Tags: jqgrid

I want to take advantage of the sortableRows property of the jqGrid.  How do I detect when a row has been moved.  I have studied the documentation and looked for examples but haven't found much. I do believe it is something like

```
jQuery("#grid").sortableRows({connectWith:'#gird',
                              ondrop: function(){ alert("row moved") }});
```

but that does not work.  I can move the rows, but don't seemed to have trapped the event.  Is there something wrong with my syntax or my approach in general.

Basically, I need to know that the rows have been rearranged so  I can be sure they get saved with their new order.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

jqGrid uses the ui-sortable plugin to sort rows: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/.
In

```
jQuery("#grid").sortableRows( options )
```

"options" is the passed to the sortable plugin.

```
options = { update : function(e,ui){} }
```

is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Attach the sortstop event handler to your grid:

```
jQuery("#grid").bind('sortstop', function(event, ui) { alert("row moved") });
```

I did a quick test and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#'+grid_id).jqGrid('sortableRows', {
                    update: function (event, ui) {
                        var newOrder = $('#'+grid_id).jqGrid("getDataIDs");
                        //do whatever you want with new roworder
                        //please keep in mind this will give only page visible rows
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer, and how it differs from the existing answers.

Comment: According to DW, the question needs to trap row movement event and want new row order so I give little more code here. there is nothing different with existing[Marks answer], I just give more detailing