# Using JQgrid and sortableRows. Update table row order

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Using: [Using SortableRows and know when rows have been moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382879/using-sortablerows-and-know-when-rows-have-been-moved) I have been able to call an alert after the modification of my row order.

How would I send this data to PHP/ call the editurl passing this data, similar to when adding or editing rows the editurl receives a $_POST['oper'] variable?

Currently have:

```
jQuery("#images_list").jqGrid('sortableRows',
                              options = { update : function(e,ui){alert("hi");} });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all the usage of update event should be like following:

```
jQuery("#images_list").jqGrid(
    'sortableRows',
    { update : function(e,ui) {
                   alert("item with id=" + ui.item[0].id + " is droped");
               }
    });
```

If you need other row data, you can get there using the id of the row moved and `getRowData` method.

How to post the results to the server you should decide yourself. You can use `$.ajax` function directly. I think, that changing of order of rows should not be interpret as an adding, deleting or editing of rows.