# JqGrid: drop event does NOT get fired when draging and dropping a row in the SAME grid

Tags: jqgrid, drag-and-drop

I am hoping to catch the drop event when dragging and droping a row in the same grid.

I am looking the "Sortable Rows" example listed here (version 3.6)

http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

I am able to replicate this example locally. Instead of using

```
jQuery("#sortrows").jqGrid('sortableRows');
```

from the example, I used the following:

```
jQuery("#sortrows").jqGrid('sortableRows', {
   ondrop: function (ev, ui, getdata) {
     alert('fired');
   }    
});
```

I did not change anything else. However, the ondrop event seems not fired when I drop a row.

How to catch drop and other events in my situation?

BTW, what is the normal strategy of refreshing the table after drag/drop, if I have a grid with rows of alternating colors?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

I found this post:

[Using SortableRows and know when rows have been moved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382879/using-sortablerows-and-know-when-rows-have-been-moved)

which mentions:

```
jQuery("#grid").sortableRows( options )

"options" is the passed to the sortable plugin.

options = { update : function(e,ui){} }
```

In the update method, I used the following:

```
$(grid_selector).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Hope this helps. Love to hear better solutions.